# Checking Font Styles In Word Document Using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-word, office-interop

i want to check a word file using vb.net and check that the styles in the document are proper or not.

I have to check for these expressions in word document

`a.Verdana + 16 pt + Bold + Red`

`b.Verdana + 12 pt + Bold + Italic + Blue`

`c.Verdana + 11 pt + Bold + Italic + Brown`

`d.Arial + 10 pt + Black`

I have tried this,

```
If objDoc.Range.Font.Name = "Arial" And objDoc.Range.Font.Size = 10 Then
   If objDoc.Range.Font.Color = WdColor.wdColorBlack Then
   End If
        MsgBox("ok")
    Else
        MsgBox("not ok")
End If
```

But with this code it shows msgbox "OK" only when the whole word document consist of `Arial,10,Black` and shows msgbox "Not Ok" when it consist the above expressions except for the `Arial,10,Black`

So basically i need help to find out all the expressions in the same word document which consist of all the above expressions/Styles.

Any Help will be really really appreciable..
Plz help me with this still not able to find a solution..

Comment: Have you been able to write any code? I am not familiar with Interop for Word, so I don't have any suggestions for you. However, if you provide a bit of code in your question and show what you have tried you are more likely to get help from others on the site.

Comment: I have updated my question please check it out..

Comment: It's not necessary to add "[UPDATED]" to your title. There's an edit history maintained here. Everyone can see your post has been updated.

Comment: k thanks can u help me with the solution of the above question

Comment: I started to, but your question does not match your code. Your code checks `objDoc.Range`, but you're not showing how you set that `Range`. If it's only matching the whole document, then you've set the `Range` to include the whole document. One Range can't possibly be all of those styles at the same time. It's not really clear what you're asking here.

Comment: actually i have to check the above possibilities in word documents if all of the above expressions match in the document its fine, if not it should pop up an error message...is it possible to do so.??

Comment: @Winky, you should explain what is wrong with the answer that you decided to open bounty. If you face any problem you should open new question and explain exactly what is wrong!

Comment: @ Winky ask a fresh question ill post my answer there i can try and make this process faster

Comment: and post ur questions link here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the foolowing code you can find sentences where font style is different.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim oDoc As New Word.Document()
    Dim wapp As New Word.Application()

    Try
        oDoc = wapp.Documents.Open(TextBox1.Text & "\" & "TEST.doc")

        For Each Senetence As Word.Range In oDoc.Sentences
            For Each Character As Word.Range In Senetence.Characters
                If Character.Font.Name <> "Verdana" AndAlso Character.Font.Name <> "Arial" Then
                    MsgBox(" Font Name not matching Error Line number " & Senetence.Text)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next
        oDoc.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        oDoc.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: does it help to find sentence even font size is different? @TithiPatel

Comment: @Winky yes u can set font-size value u want to set For eg : `If Character.Font.Name = "Verdana" AndAlso Character.Font.size = 12 Then else msgbox("Error" & Sentence.Text)` this will read the sentences and check for the above styles if any characters in sentence does not consist the above style it will display that particular sentence.